# Python Tkinter Memory Game- onClick Problem

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick

I'm trying to build a memory game with images that i've selected.I am using Tkinter and Python I can create the buttons but there is something wrong with my function that is not allowing me to see the image after clicking on the button. I can make it work if I stick with numbers instead of images so i know that is where my problem lies.

I created the list of buttons and set their default image to be white. I created a list holding the images that I want to show. onClick I want to go through the image list and change the button image to the one from the list.

Any help is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

game = Tk()
game.title('Memory Game Challenge')
game.geometry("800x1100")

# Images
base =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/white.jpeg").resize((125, 125)))
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/red_1.png").resize((125, 125)))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/red_2.png").resize((125, 125)))
img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/red_3.png").resize((125, 125)))
img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/red_4.png").resize((125, 125)))
img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/brown_1.png").resize((125, 125)))
img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/brown_2.png").resize((125, 125)))
img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/brown_3.png").resize((125, 125)))
img8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("/Users/a/PycharmProjects/Images/brown_4.png").resize((125, 125)))

# Creating list for matches
matches = [img1, img1, img2, img2, img3, img3, img4, img4, img5, img5, img6, img6, img7, img7, img8, img8]

# Shuffle matches
random.shuffle(matches)

# Create Easy Frame 4 * 4
easy_frame = Frame(game)
easy_frame.pack(pady=10)

# Define Variables
count = 0
answer_list = []
answer_dictionary = {}


# Define function for clicking the button
def button_click(b, number):
    global count, answer_list, answer_dictionary

    if b["image"] == base and count < 2:
        b["image"] = matches[number]
        # adding the number to answer list
        answer_list.append(number)
        # Adding number and button to answer dictionary
        answer_dictionary[b] = matches[number]
        # Increment count
        count += 1

    # Determine if they match
    if len(answer_list) == 2:
        if matches[answer_list[0]] == matches[answer_list[1]]:
            match_label.config(text="Your Found a Match")
            for key in answer_dictionary:
                key["state"] = "disable"
             count = 0
             answer_list = []
             answer_dictionary = {}
        else:
            match_label.config(text="Try again")
            count = 0
            answer_list = []

            # Reset buttons to be blank
            for key in answer_dictionary:
                key["image"] = base

            answer_dictionary = {}


# Create Buttons for layout
b0 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b0, 0))
b1 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b1, 1))
b2 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b2, 2))
b3 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b3, 3))
b4 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b4, 4))
b5 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b5, 5))
b6 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b6, 6))
b7 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b7, 7))
b8 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b8, 8))
b9 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b9, 9))
b10 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b10, 10))
b11 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b11, 11))
b12 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b12, 12))
b13 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b13, 13))
b14 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b14, 14))
b15 = Button(easy_frame, image=base, height=125, width=125, command=lambda: button_click(b15, 15))

# Assign buttons to Grid
b0.grid(row=0, column=0)
b1.grid(row=0, column=1)
b2.grid(row=0, column=2)
b3.grid(row=0, column=3)

b4.grid(row=1, column=0)
b5.grid(row=1, column=1)
b6.grid(row=1, column=2)
b7.grid(row=1, column=3)

b8.grid(row=2, column=0)
b9.grid(row=2, column=1)
b10.grid(row=2, column=2)
b11.grid(row=2, column=3)

b12.grid(row=3, column=0)
b13.grid(row=3, column=1)
b14.grid(row=3, column=2)
b15.grid(row=3, column=3)

match_label = Label(game, text="")
match_label.pack(pady=20)

game.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `b["image"]` returns the internal name (a string) of the image used in the button, but `base` is an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`, so `b["image"] == base` will always be `False`.  Use `b["image"] == str(base)` instead.

Also you need to *force update* the selected button and put a short sleep to let user to see the actual images of them.

Below is the modified `button_click()`:

```py
# Define function for clicking the button
def button_click(b, number):
    global count, answer_list, answer_dictionary

    # use str(base) instead of base
    if b["image"] == str(base) and count < 2:
        b["image"] = matches[number]
        # adding the number to answer list
        answer_list.append(number)
        # Adding number and button to answer dictionary
        answer_dictionary[b] = matches[number]
        # Increment count
        count += 1

    # Determine if they match
    if len(answer_list) == 2:
        if matches[answer_list[0]] == matches[answer_list[1]]:
            match_label.config(text="Your Found a Match")
            for key in answer_dictionary:
                key["state"] = "disable"
            count = 0
            answer_list = []
            answer_dictionary = {}
        else:
            match_label.config(text="Try again")
            game.update() # force update the button
            game.after(500)  # sleep a short period (half second)
            count = 0
            answer_list = []

            # Reset buttons to be blank
            for key in answer_dictionary:
                key["image"] = base

            answer_dictionary = {}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! That makes a lot more sense. I was also trying to figure out the sleep part but couldn't quite work out where it needed to go!